# How to solve java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, kotlin

When I write this code in kotlin customadapter

It always crashes with the following **error**:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is
>   null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull,
>   parameter listCountry

The completed code:

**CustomAdapter.kt**

```
class CustomAdapter(var context: Context,val  listCountry: List<Model.Country>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.CustomHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, position: Int): CustomHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_recycler,parent,false)

        return  CustomHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = listCountry.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomHolder, position: Int) {

        val flag = listCountry[position]

        Glide.with(context).load(flag.image).into(holder.countryFlag)

        holder.numCode.text = flag.numcode

        holder.countryName.text = flag.name

    }

    class CustomHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val numCode : TextView =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCountryCode)
        val countryName : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCountryName)
        val countryFlag : ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivCountryFlag)
    }

}
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val apiservice = RetrofitClient().getClient()!!.create(RetrofitApiInterface::class.java)

    val call : Call<Model> = apiservice.getData()

    call.enqueue(object : Callback<Model>{
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<Model>?, t: Throwable?) {
            Log.e("Failure",t.toString())
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<Model>?, response: Response<Model>?) {
            Log.e("Response","This is Successfull Response")

            val listCountry = response!!.body().data.countryList

            recyclerList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
            recyclerList.adapter = CustomAdapter(this@MainActivity,listCountry)
                //Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"Successfull",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    })
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this constructor for your adapter, which takes a non-null `List<Model.Country>`:

```
class CustomAdapter(var context: Context, val listCountry: List<Model.Country>)
```

And then you take data from a network response and pass that in as the parameter to the constructor:

```
val listCountry = response!!.body().data.countryList
...
recyclerList.adapter = CustomAdapter(this@MainActivity, listCountry)
```

This is where you get a crash, because somehow `listCountry` ended up containing a `null` value.

Chances are that one of these two things are going wrong here:

- If your model class here is written in Java, this `countryList` will have a [platform type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types), so it's up to you to decide whether you want to treat it as nullable.
- Even if your model is written in Kotlin and the `countryList` property is non-nullable in it, if you use a serialization tool that uses reflection to instantiate models (e.g. Gson), a `null` value may still be written in that property, if that's what the network responded with.

As for a solution: type this list explicitly as nullable (in case of the platform type issue, here in your code, otherwise in your network model), and then perform the null checks that the compiler forces on you:

```
val listCountry: List<Model.Country>? = response!!.body().data.countryList
...
if (listCountry != null) {
    recyclerList.adapter = CustomAdapter(this@MainActivity, listCountry)
} else {
    // handle missing part of network response somehow
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because response and countryList can be null: response!!.body().data.countryList
You have to check it.

```
response?.body().data.countryList?.let {
        recyclerList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
        recyclerList.adapter = CustomAdapter(this@MainActivity, it)
    }
```

usage !! for nullable is a bad practice